# What's the right way to think about and measure the quality of this classifier?

Tags: classification

I am doing blind wine taste tests and I want quantitative measures of how good people are. The procedure is:

1. Test subject becomes familiar with wines A and B.
2. For `n` trials:

   1. Test runner randomly selects a wine.
   2. Test subject receives the randomly selected wine, blindly.
   3. Test subject tastes the wine.
   4. Test subject says what wine (A or B) they think it is.

At the end, you have a dataset like:

```
_Actual_    _Guessed_
A           A
A           B
B           A
B           B
```

### Questions

1. Is this a binary classifier, because you're choosing between two wines? Is a binary classifier equivalent to a multiclass identifier with two classes?
2. How should I evaluate performance? (The goal is to see who is best able to accurately identify wines.) A few ideas:

   1. Create a confusion matrix as noted on [Evaluation of binary classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers).
   2. Generate another sequence of classifications by flipping a coin for each decision, then running a t-test to see how different the two sequences are.

      - That seems like it's probably not what we want, because a t-test is for normally distributed variables, which this is not.
   3. Calculate the probability of a coin flip classifier yielding the same results as the person.

      - This seems like it's not as good, because being different from a coin flip could be in either a good way or a bad way. A number that just tells you if a classifier's predictions are different from a coin flip does not tell you if that is a positive or negative difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a binary classifier and yes a binary is a multi class with 2 classes. I think the best way to measure your classifier is
 accuracy, tp/(tp+tn+fp+fn). 
And the f1 score which is the harmonic mean of the precision (tp/tp+fp) and recall (tp/tp+fn)